# What is the standard for choosing "when" vs "if/else" in Kotlin?

Tags: java, if-statement, kotlin, switch-statement

I'm making the transfer from Java to Kotlin, and learning about the varied differences between the Java switch and the Kotlin when statement.

My question is, do the differences change the standard for when you choose "when" over a series of "if" and "else if" blocks?

For example, in Java "switch" is generally more efficient than "else-ifs" when there are 5 or more cases, and roughly comparable otherwise. If-else is generally preferred when the statements are boolean. Is this similar in Kotlin? Are there other reasons that differ to Java that I should consider when writing my code - ie standards for readability etc.

I would appreciate answers or links to more in depth reading on the subject - I have struggled to find any sources that do a good cost-benefit analysis.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kotlin benefits over java is [concise](https://superkotlin.com/kotlin-when-statement/) syntax

> when has a better design. It is more concise and powerful than a traditional switch

Also more [readable](https://superkotlin.com/kotlin-when-statement/) related to if else:

> when is that it can be used without an argument. In such case it acts as a **nicer if-else chain**: the conditions are Boolean expressions. As always, the first branch that matches is chosen. Given that these are boolean expression, it means that the first condition that results True is chosen.
>
> ```
> when {
>     number > 5 -> print("number is higher than five")
>     text == "hello" -> print("number is low, but you can say hello")
> }
> ```
>
> The advantage is that a when **expression is cleaner and easier to understand** than a chain of if-else statements.

Comment: Yes, I do love that it is much more readable. I'm wondering when I would want to apply an if-else chain? Only when the contents of each statement are more complicated and requiring indentation? Or are there cases where if-else is preferred for single line cases as well..

Comment: @Roonil it may be more opinion/user preference based

Comment: @Roonil You can have multiple lines in a `when` branch, no problem.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov oh yeah for sure, I just feel like it looks messy with a when branch. Maybe that's just personal preference. Cheers.

Answer (score 21):

From the [Kotlin Coding Conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#if-versus-when):
Prefer using `if` for binary conditions. Prefer using `when` if there are three or more options.

Edit: Interesting wrinkle, `when` statements must be exhaustive, so I'll ignore this standard if I'm switching over an enum with only two values, to benefit from the compile error should the enum expand.

Answer (score 4):

I searched for this comparison and the answers didn't convince me that much, until I read the [control flow doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html) from kotlin

Using ***When*** is like saying goodbye to both ***if*** and ***switch*** statements;

Also on top of that you can return when like below:

```
   fun whatPosition(number: Int) : String{
        return when(number){
            1 -> "First"
            2 -> "Second"
            3 -> "Third"
            else -> "Loser"
        }
    }
```

Still learning Kt and i am stunned by how much less we need to write and does more than what java can.

Comment: You can still return with if/else in the same way

Comment: true, but it would look like return if(condition1){...} else if(condition2){...}... i like this syntactic sugar and i know behind the scenes its converted to bytecode that will become a classic conditional statement. But i would prefer the readability of `when` over `if` any time with kotlin